# Trying to number each line of my results

Tags: php

I'm trying to display sequential weeks based on values placed into a form, I have some code I wrote that works but the issue I am having is I can't seem to get the "week #" to work correctly and I was hoping that someone could let me know where I went wrong

```
    <?php

$teams = $_REQUEST['teams'];
$weeks = $_REQUEST['weeks'];
$rounds = $_REQUEST['rounds'];
$start = new DateTime($_REQUEST['start']);
$end = new DateTime($_REQUEST['end']);
$end = $end->modify( '+1 week' );

$a = array($weeks, $rounds);
echo "Length of Session = " . array_product($a) . " weeks"."<br>" . "\n";

for($i = 0; $i<=array_product($a); $i++){
}

$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo "week $i   -   " . $date->format("m/d/Y") . "<br>";
}

?>
```

This code is displaying the following:

```
Length of Session = 20 weeks
week 21 - 11/14/2017
week 21 - 11/21/2017
week 21 - 11/28/2017
week 21 - 12/05/2017
week 21 - 12/12/2017
week 21 - 12/19/2017
week 21 - 12/26/2017
week 21 - 01/02/2018
week 21 - 01/09/2018
week 21 - 01/16/2018
week 21 - 01/23/2018
week 21 - 01/30/2018
week 21 - 02/06/2018
week 21 - 02/13/2018
week 21 - 02/20/2018
week 21 - 02/27/2018
week 21 - 03/06/2018
week 21 - 03/13/2018
week 21 - 03/20/2018
week 21 - 03/27/2018
```

Comment: You have two separate loops for your `$i` and your dates. If you just want to  increment `$i` for each of your dates, remove the first `for`loop, and simply increment `$i` in your `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your corrected code.  You don't need the `for` loop.  Just initialize the `$i` variable before your foreach loop, and then increment it inside the `foreach` loop:

```
$teams = $_REQUEST['teams'];
$weeks = $_REQUEST['weeks'];
$rounds = $_REQUEST['rounds'];
$start = new DateTime($_REQUEST['start']);
$end = new DateTime($_REQUEST['end']);
$end = $end->modify( '+1 week' );

$a = array($weeks, $rounds);
echo "Length of Session = " . array_product($a) . " weeks"."<br>" . "\n";


// You don't need this:
// for($i = 0; $i<=array_product($a); $i++){
// }

$interval = new DateInterval('P1W');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval ,$end);

$i = 1;    
foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo "week $i   -   " . $date->format("m/d/Y") . "<br>";
    $i++;
}
```